# How do I display two datepicker when I click on a dropdown box in Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui

Currently I'm trying to display two datepickers when I click on a dropdownbox.

However I have trouble trying to embed the datepicker inside the dropdownbox as when the dropdownbox is clicked, nothing happens. Hope someone could help me out.

```
<div class="dropdown" dropdown>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" dropdown-open>My Heroes</button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                //This is where i need to insert the below datepicker
            </ul>
        </div>

        <input id="datepicker" value="10/10/2011" style="width: 100%" />
        <input id="datepicker1" value="10/10/2011" style="width: 100%" />
```

Comment: What did you tried ? Can you post your javascript code ?

Comment: @Guillaume I'm actually using typescript because it's in Angular2. I have embedded two kendoCalendar objects inside a dropdown box instead and achieved what I was looking for.